# Maximum Weight Planarization of Size $n$

Tags: graphs, reference-request, weighted-graphs, planar-graphs

### **Problem: Maximum Weight Planarization**

1. Given a weighted non-planar graph with $n$ vertices, and $m = \mathcal O\left(n^2\right)$ edges.
2. Find the subgraph with $n$ nodes (but possibly removing edges to make it planar) that has the most weight (i.e the sum of the weight of the edges in this subgraph).

### **Questions:**

1. Is this a known problem with a name?
2. Any efficient solutions?
3. If no efficient solution is known, what about a variation when the maximum degree is limited by a constant, $k$?

Comment: @D.W. hi :), you are right, the language was wrong. I modified it ('Modified from "planar embedding" to "planar subgraph of size n"') to make more sense.

Comment: Is this a duplicate? [Heaviest planar subgraph](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/40703/2755)

Comment: Seems like it is exactly the same problem. Edges not in your graph get zero weight.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus shall I delete the question then?

Comment: We can try to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus hmm what about (3), that seems like it makes my question adds something.

Comment: Perhaps, but at this point you can do the literature search on your own.